# MySQL remove only first row

Tags: mysql

I've got a table:

[image]

Is there a way to remove only the first row with a specified id? For example (on the picture) i want to remove the row with id 8, the first row with id 9 (leave the second), remove the first with the id 11 (leave the others) etc.

Comment: What column should it order by to decide which one is "first" in each group?

Comment: By post_id, like it is.

Comment: what is the full schema of the data?

Comment: Do you have date field somewhere or you want to select any random record?

Comment: In each group they have the same post ID. How should it know which row in each group should be removed?

Comment: Do these rows not have an incrementing `id` that's unique?

Comment: No, that's the whole table.

Comment: MySQL needs to know what you mean by first. Unless you have a row other than post_id to order the fields on, the groups of post_ids will be arbitrarily ordered, and you can't be sure what will be deleted.

Comment: I would guess that post_id keys to another table. You may need to join to that table get a meaningful order.

Comment: You only want to delete one from post ID 8, 9, and 11, but not 10?

Comment: The table is bigger, to post_id = 1069

Comment: But do you want to do this for every ID, or just selected IDs? Did you skip 10 in the question for a reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will delete the first row in each `post_id` group, using `meta_value` as the ordering.

```
DELETE t1.* FROM yourTable AS t1
JOIN (SELECT post_id, min(meta_value) AS min_meta
      FROM yourTable
      GROUP BY post_id) AS t2
ON t1.post_id = t2.post_id AND t1.meta_value = t2.min_meta
```

Comment: I'm getting error: #1064 - Something is wrong in your syntax 'AS t2.min_meta' on line 5